# STDIN from Makefile with make run command

Tags: python-3.x, makefile, compilation, stdin

I have a program in which I'm trying to invoke the following command:

```
make run {FILE} e.g filename.txt
```

How can I create my Makefile so it can execute this program and accept any filename through STDIN.

My Makefile looks like the following:

```
run:
   python execute.py --filename {ANY FILENAME}
```

Comment: Nothing about this question has anything to do with STDIN, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The arguments to `make` are targets. There's no special relationship between `run` and `{FILE}` in your initial example. If you want to force the `run` prefix, it'll have to be part of the target name, instead of space separated:

```
run-%:
    python execute.py --filename $*
```

Comment: Thanks Carl. I keep getting (make: *** No rule to make target `run'.  Stop.) and If I remove "-%:" from the run command I'm getting (make: Nothing to be done for data.txt) data.txt is my input filename

Comment: You need to use `make run-data.txt`.

Comment: So there is no way we can have the command `make run run-data.txt` to run the python script without getting that error? is there a workaround?

Comment: That's just not how `make` works. If you want to parse command line arguments, write a script instead.